# Error message appears when using super.init()

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I've been trying to be hereditary since recently. Since then the following error appears in GameViewController.swift: `Cannot convert value of type 'CGSize' to expected argument type 'NSCoder'`

**GameViewController.swift**

```
    class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let scene = GameScene(coder: self.view.bounds.size) //here is the error
        let skview = self.view as! SKView
        skview.showsFPS = true
        skview.showsNodeCount = true
        skview.showsPhysics = false

        skview.presentScene(scene)

    }

}
```

I would be very grateful for any answer, as I have already been sitting on this problem for several hours.

Comment: Your code compiles just fine, doesn't produce the error mentioned. You should [edit] your question with the actual code producing the error in the form of a [mcve].

Comment: My best guess is that you've implemented `init(coder:)` and are calling `super` with an incorrect parameter. If you're not planning on loading the scene from a scene file you can implement `init(coder:)` with just a `fatalError("Unsupported")` call.

Comment: Also, the reason you're getting downvotes and close votes is because the code you are showing is not related at all to the error you're mentioning. For future questions, make sure you post the code that is causing the errors. You'll get better answers.

Comment: I hope that I display the correct code yet

Comment: So what do you expect to happen when you call `GameScene(coder:)` with a `CGSize` argument instead of an `NSCoder`?

Comment: Actually, I had written this before: `let scene = GameScene(size: self.view.bounds.size)`. But then I get the following error: `Incorrect argument label in call (have 'size:', expected 'coder:')`. It suggests me: `Replace 'size' with 'coder'`

Comment: `let scene = GameScene(size: self.view.bounds.size)` compiles fine. Can you share any demo project where you are getting same error?

Comment: May I send it to your email address shown on your profile? @DharmeshKheni

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have checked your code and you need to remove

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

From your `GameScene.swift` file.